# Converting simple military hour standard time

Tags: javascript

I have a time range expressed in military hours, e.g.

```
10-14
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
10:00 am - 2:00 pm
```

I came up with something like this, but I think it's a bit too convoluted. Can it be simplified even further?

```js
var hrFr = "10",
    hrTo = "14";

var t  = (hrFr > 12 ? hrFr - 12 : hrFr) + ':00';
    t += (hrFr >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am') + ' - '
    t += (hrTo == 24 ? ' midnignt' : (hrTo > 12 ? hrTo - 12 : hrTo) + ':00' +  (hrTo >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am'));
    
alert(t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudn't duplicate the conversion:

```
function convHour( hr ) {
    return (hr == 24 ? 'midnight' : (hr > 12 ? hr - 12 : hr) + ':00' +  (hr >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am')
}

var t = convHour( hrFr ) +  ' - ' + convHour( hrto );
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming they are always whole numbers, may need to dress up a little for minutes

```
function adjustTime(hrTo)
{
    return ((hrTo == 24 || hrTo == 0) ? ' midnight' : (hrTo > 12 ? hrTo - 12 : hrTo) + ':00' + (hrTo >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am'));
}
```

I like this more because if the specs change, you don't have to reparse both to and from, just the function

Comment: It now returns 0:00 for `adjustTime(0)`. Consider `return hrTo==24? 'midnight' : (hrTo%12 || 12 + ':00' + (hrTo<12? 'am' : 'pm'));`

Comment: fixed. i assume the modulus is to handle things like 25 though i didn't check.. if that's the case, i am opting to not go that route since what if hrFrom = 25 but hrTo is 12? Handling all possible variations and ensuring it is all validated seems way beyond the scope of answering the question 'how can i clean this up', which in my opinion was demonstrated by showing the use of a function as opposed to hard coding the parsing for each time.

As an fyi, it looks like your snippet only applies the am pm modifiers for noon.and the 00 parsings of midnight

Comment: It's for 0 to 24, with 24 returning "midnight" (which is more commonly called "12:00 am") and 12 returning "12:00 pm", which seems to be the OP's requirement. But I may be wrong about that, the requirement isn't clearly stated.